# Android asynchronously fetch data from db

Tags: android, mysql, multithreading, fetch

I need a safe practise to load data from the Database.
I need to load the data from the Sql db and put it into a list or recylerview.
So what i tryied, i created a class which call the method load more everytime when user reaches the end of the list. And than it load the data limited.
Like 'Select * From a Where 1 Limit listItemCount, 20'.
I run into problems with this because, the thread which was loading, started 2 times with the same count value. Than i have changed it to synch the global run method from the loading thread. And accessing the count from the background worker of the list. This helped me a lot, and the data was loaded  correctly, but i got still troubles with this. Because i need to insert the data into listview from the background thread, because of the synchronisation and calling notify in main thread after. If i am not doing it like this, i will get still problem.

- Thread A: Started work.
- Thread B: Waiting for finishing thread A (synchronized)
- Thread A: runOnUiThread() trying to fill data.
- Thread B: Allowed to run the code, getting count from listView.
- Thread B: Got the same count as A, because A not finished the insert
  statement.
- Thread A: Added data.
- Thread B: Added same data.

After this i added a atomicboolean, that if the thread is running he is just not executed. With this it was working perfect, but sometimes you have to scroll up a bit and down to trigger the load more.
And i think this solution is a bit dirty for me. Anyone now how to load data in pieces depending on list size of the listview, in a background thread without this issues?

This method is getting called when reaching the end of list:

```
private ExecutorService executorService;
    private void loadMore()
    {
        if(!isAdded())
            return;

        if(executorService == null)
            executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        executorService.execute(new AsyncLoadMoreHashTags(getContext(), this, esaphTagAdapterVertical));
    }
```

Background Thread:

```
public class AsyncLoadMoreHashTags extends MyDataLoaderClass
{
    private static final Object obLock = new Object();

    public AsyncLoadMoreHashTags(Context context, DataBaseLoadWaiter dataBaseLoadWaiter, SpecialRecylerView spRecylerView)
    {
        super(context, dataBaseLoadWaiter, spRecylerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        super.run();
        synchronized (AsyncLoadMoreHashTags.obLock)
        {
            List<Object> objectList = null;
            try
            {
                int startFrom = super.getStartFrom()[0];
                SQLHashtags sqlHashtags = new SQLHashtags(super.getSoftReferenceContext().get());

                if(startFrom <= 0)
                {
                    objectList = sqlHashtags.getMostUsedHashtags();
                }
                else
                {
                    objectList = sqlHashtags.getAllHashtagLimited(startFrom);
                }

                sqlHashtags.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ec)
            {
                Log.i(getClass().getName(), "AsyncLoadMoreHashTags run() failed: " + ec);
            }
            finally
            {
                publish(objectList);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

What i need is to, just start one thread a time.
Anyone a idea?

Answer (score 0):

First of all use You should have to use [PagedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList) library provided by **google**, for implementing paging facility, and if you want to use **background thread** for **database operations** you can use [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) ***commons*** to do this. Here is an example,

```
 internal val pagedList by lazy {
        runBlocking { // Coroutine Context
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                // Read from database, and it will be initialised in background
            }
        }
    }
```

and if you want something to be **dispatched on UI** but **performed in Background** Thread, then go with this, **doAsync** operation and then return data in **uiThread** by using a custom interface.

```
 doAsync {
            // LONG OPERATION
            Thread.sleep(2000)

            uiThread {
                callback.onActionsDone(dataList)
            }
        }
```

Let me know if you want more help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with like this, working fine.

```
public class AsyncLoadMoreHashTags extends OwnDataLoader
{
    private static AtomicBoolean obLock = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public AsyncLoadMoreHashTags(Context context, DataBaseLoadWaiter dataBaseLoadWaiter, MomentsRecylerView momentsRecylerView)
    {
        super(context, dataBaseLoadWaiter, momentsRecylerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        super.run();
        if(!AsyncLoadMoreHashTags.obLock.compareAndSet(false, true)) //when any thread  loading data, its return and skips.
            return;

        List<Object> objectList = null;
        try
        {
            int startFrom = super.getStartFrom()[0];
            SQLHashtags sqlHashtags = new SQLHashtags(super.getSoftReferenceContext().get());

            if(startFrom <= 0)
            {
                objectList = sqlHashtags.getMostUsedHashtags();
            }
            else
            {
                objectList = sqlHashtags.getAllHashtagLimited(startFrom);
            }

            sqlHashtags.close();
            System.out.println("TEST: "  + startFrom + " LOAD: " + objectList.size());
        }
        catch (Exception ec)
        {
            Log.i(getClass().getName(), "AsyncLoadMoreHashTags run() failed: " + ec);
        }
        finally
        {
            publish(objectList, AsyncLoadMoreHashTags.obLock); //Passing the lock object, when data has been added, obLock.set(false); is called.
        }
    }
}
```